# Access Java variable value in JavaScript function

Tags: java, javascript, blackberry-webworks

In my Phonegap Blackberry application, how can I access native Java variable value in JavaScript function?

Answer (score 0):

Write a plugin to access the variable. Specifically specify a getter API in you native java code and access it via a plugin (or probably make you native java class a first class Phonegap plugin). See [this](http://catchmayuri.blogspot.in/2011/05/getting-access-of-android-java-code-to.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply saury. But the problem is, how can I do it for native Blackberry Java code?

Comment: cant you access that native java code from native PG plugin ?

Comment: I have developed a plugin and calling a Java method in Javascript, but I need to access the Java variable that I set in JavaScript function.

Comment: Try this guide instead - http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/guide_plugin-development_blackberry_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20BlackBerry

Answer (score 0):

You can use thymeleaf if it is possible in your application..it allows to access the getter from the java classes..

For example..

```
var name = /*[[${customer.firstName}]]*/ "";
```

this calls the getter method `getfirstName()` and return the firstname of the current customer from the `Customer` class.

Hope this helps.